# Com esta regra abaixo, como faço para mostrar o primeiro e o sobrenome do usuário no banco de dados?

Tags: php, yii

Exemplo do nome que está no DB: **José ALberto da Silva Nogueira.**
Gostaria que mostrasse apenas **José Nogueira.**

```
<?php if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) echo Yii::$app->session->get('nomeUsuario'); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue código:

```
if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    $nomeCompleto = Yii::$app->session->get('nomeUsuario');
    $partes = explode(" ", $nomeCompleto);
    echo $partes[0] . " " . $partes[count($partes) - 1];
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Jhonatan.